# PHP Reading xml attribute from XML file

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Barcodes>
    <Goods>
        <Good ID="1" Name="cc" TechnicalNumber="DN11060122D" SpecialGood="True" Desc="" />
        <Good ID="2" Name="bb" TechnicalNumber="DN11068384B" SpecialGood="True" Desc="" />
    </Goods>
</Barcodes>
```

I try to read each attribute separately, but I can not see anything in my output.

My PHP:

```
 <?php

    $folder = "C:/wamp/upload/";        
    $path   = $folder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) 
    {        
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("C:/wamp/upload/joomla.xml") 
               or die("Error: Cannot create object");

        foreach($xml->children() as $Goods)
        {
            foreach($Goods->children() as $Good => $data)
            {
                echo $data->ID;
                echo $data->Name;
                echo $data->TechnicalNumber;
                echo "<br />";
            }
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can access attributes via array operator:

```
foreach($Goods->children() as $Good => $data){
  echo $data['ID'];
  echo $data['Name'];
  echo $data['TechnicalNumber'];
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If ziollek's answer doesn't make much sense.

(it is entirely correct, but it expresses something odd about this object's behaviour...)

You can try this:

```
  foreach($xml->children() as $Goods ){
    foreach($Goods->children() as $Good ){
      $GoodAttributes = $Good->attributes();
      echo $GoodAttributes['ID'];
      echo $GoodAttributes['Name'];
      echo $GoodAttributes['TechnicalNumber'];
      echo "<br />";
    }
  }
```

If I was to var_dump one of your objects, I would get something like this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(2) "bb"
    ["TechnicalNumber"]=>
    string(11) "DN11068384B"
    ["SpecialGood"]=>
    string(4) "True"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

That is, the `SimpleXMLElement` has a member variable that contains the attributes as an array.

The class has an overloaded accessor, so that you can reference these attributes as if the `SimpleXMLELement` itself was an array.  As an aside a similar thing is done to make the child nodes available as if they were public member variables.

I was always a little taken aback by the object that is also an array behaviour, and preferred to ask the object for its attributes, by using the method `attributes()`

It's probably just a personal taste thing, and I never produced anything with `simplexml_load_file` that needed to perform, so there may be some overheads with this alternative technique that I'm not aware of.

I just wanted to make you aware of the options...

Comment: Thank you :) your explanation is helpful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access attributes not elements itself

```
 foreach($xml->children() as $Goods)
    {
        foreach($Goods->children() as $data)
        {
            echo $data->attributes()->ID;
            echo $data->attributes()->Name;
            echo $data->attributes()->TechnicalNumber;
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
```